# Rotate the rows of a matrix (like GAUSS function rotater)

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, statistics, linear-algebra

I'm currently bringing some *GAUSS* code over to *Matlab* and I'm stuck trying to use the GAUSS "rotater" function.

The command reference entry for rotater says:

- **Purpose** Rotates the rows of a matrix
- **Format** y = rotater(x,r)
- **Input** x: N x K matrix to be rotated. r: N x 1 or 1 x 1 matrix specifying the amount of rotation.
- **Output** y: N x K rotated matrix.
- **Remarks** The rotation is performed horizontally within each row of the matrix. A positive rotation value will cause the elements to move
  to the right. A negative rotation will cause the elements to move to
  the left. In either case, the elements that are pushed off the end of
  the row will wrap around to the opposite end of the same row. If the rotation value is greater than or equal to the number of columns in x, then the rotation value will be calculated using (r % cols(x)).

**Example 1** 
(I'm following Matlab's notation here, with straight brackets for matrices and a semicolon for a new ro)

If x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6], and r = [1; -1],then y = [3 1 2; 5 6 4]

**Example 1**

If x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10, 11, 12], and r = [0; 1; 2; 3], then y = [1 2 3; 6 4 5; 8 9 7; 10 11 12]

Maybe someone has found a function like that somewhere or can give me advice how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) twice:

1. Compute rotated row indices by subtracting `r` with `bsxfun` and using [`mod`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html). As usual, `mod` needs indices starting at `0`, not `1`. The rotated row indices are left as 0-based, because that's more convenient for step 2.
2. Get a [linear index](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) from columns and rotated rows, again using `bsxfun`. This linear index applied to `x` gives `y`:

Code:

```
[s1 s2] = size(x);
rows = mod(bsxfun(@plus, 1:s2, -r(:))-1, s2);  % // step 1
y = x(bsxfun(@plus, rows*s1, (1:s1).'));       %'// step 2
```

Comment: I knew there was a `bsxfun` solution lurking about... ;)

Answer (score 0):

[circshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) is pretty close to what you're looking for except that 1) it works on columns rather than rows, and 2) it shifts the entire matrix by the same offset.

The first one is easy to fix, we just transpose. For the second one I haven't been able to find a vectorized approach, but in the meantime, here's a version with a for loop:

```
x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]
r = [0 1 2 3]

B = x'

C = zeros(size(B));
for ii = 1:size(B,2)
  C(:,ii) = circshift(B(:,ii),r(ii));
end

y = C'
```

The output is:

```
x =

    1    2    3
    4    5    6
    7    8    9
   10   11   12

r =

   0   1   2   3

B =

    1    4    7   10
    2    5    8   11
    3    6    9   12

y =

    1    2    3
    6    4    5
    8    9    7
   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple for loop to iterate over each row, and a function called '[circshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html)' from matlab.

I created a function the goes through each row and applies the appropriate shift to it. There may be more efficient ways to implement this, but this way works with your examples. I created a function

```erlang
function rotated_arr = GaussRotate(input_array, rotation_vector)
    [N,K] = size(input_array)

    %creates array for return values
    rotated_arr = zeros(N,K);

    %if the rotation vector is a scalar
    if (length(rotation_vector) == 1)
        %replicate the value once for each row
        rotation_vector = repmat(rotation_vector, [1,N]);
    end

    %if the rotation vector doesn't have as many entries as there are rows
    %in the input array
    if (length(rotation_vector) ~= N)
        disp('ERROR GaussRotate: rotation_vector is the wrong size')
        disp('if input_Array is NxK, rotation_vector must be Nx1 or 1x1')
        return
    end

    %for each row
    for idx=1:size(input_array,1)
        %shift the row by the appropriate number of columns
        %we use [0,shift] because we want to shift the columns, the row
        %stays where it is (even though this is a 1xN at this point we
        %still specify rows vs columns)
        rotated_arr(idx,:) = circshift(input_array(idx,:),[0,rotation_vector(idx)]);
    end

end
```

then simply called it with your examples

```erlang
 x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
 r = [1; -1];
 y =  GaussRotate(x,r)
 %produces [3 1 2; 5 6 4]

 %I also made it support the 1x1 case
 r = [-1] 
 %this will shift all elements one column to the left
 y = GaussRotate(x,r)
 %produces [2 3 1; 5 6 4]

 x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10, 11, 12]
 r = [0; 1; 2; 3]
 y = GaussRotate(x,r)
 %produces  [1 2 3; 6 4 5; 8 9 7; 10 11 12]
```

Comment: My answer matches @beaker except instead of transpose I simply passed in arrays for  circshift (so that you can make it work on rows instead of columns) I also improved on his answer with more error checking, but both will work fine. (i would've added comments to your code beaker but I don't have enough points yet)